# Getting floating point exception while trying to use div in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to run the following code in assembly:

```
  mov        %si, %ax
  mov        $15, %si
  div        %si
  mov        %eax, %esi
```

When I make my program, it compiles, but at runtime it gives me a floating point exception.
I tried to replace the last line's parameters by `%ah` and `%si`.

Briefly, I am trying to divide `%esi` by `15`. I only want an `int`, and have no need for a `double`.

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `div` instruction divides the two-word parameter `dx/ax` by the operand. If the quotient is too large to fit into a word, it will throw that exception.

Reference: http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/DIV

What do you have in the `dx` register? Most likely `dx/ax` divided by `15` does not fit in a 16-bit word.

Comment: Nothing (or random stuff), I thought my operation was %si/%ax, which was stored into %ax

Comment: Then you'll need to clear (set to zero) the `dx` register. Because it represents the top 16-bits of the input dividend.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot, I will theck the answer in 7 minutes