# i386 Assembly floating exception on div instruction

Tags: assembly, division, i386

I have been playing with assembly recently, and when trying to use the `div` instruction, I am coming across a `Floating exception`. I have searched online for the past day or two and nothing is working. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793060/getting-floating-point-exception-while-trying-to-use-div-in-assembly), and because of the answer, I put in the three `xorq` instructions to zero out the registers (specifically `rdx` because it is the high byte of the dividend), but it still didn't help. When compiling a c program that simply does a modulus operation (and creates a few variables so the compiler doesn't optimize away the modulus) using `gcc -S myProg.c`, gcc creates an assembly file that has a `cltd` (convert signed long to signed long double) instruction right before the `idivl`. I tried that in my program as well, but it change anything. I have also tried using different size values in `rax` ans `rbx`, but it still doesn't work.

**QUESTION:** What am I doing wrong, and what weird quirks are there to using the `div` instruction? [This](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2007/readings/i386/c17.htm) is the documentation I have been using for learning assembly.

In my code below, the function `print` simply prints the contents of `rax`. I don't care what gets printed, only that something is printed so I can see which instruction crashes the program.

```
.cstring
    _format: .asciz "%d\n"

.text
.globl _main
_main:
    # program setup
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    # program - 16 byte aligned already
    # zero out the registers
    xorq    %rax, %rax
    xorq    %rdx, %rdx
    xorq    %rbx, %rbx

    # set the values to use in the division
    movq    $5, %rax
    movq    $16, %rbx

#   cltd    # 'gcc -S' command puts in cltd before idivl 
    call    print
    idivl   %ebx, %eax     ########### CRASH HERE
    call    print

    # program cleanup
    popq    %rbp
    ret

# prints value in %rax (could be junk, I don't care. As long as something is printed)
print:
    subq    $8, %rsp    # for 16 byte alignment
    lea     _format(%rip), %rdi
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    call    _printf
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

Comment: You make a call to `print` right before the `idiv` instruction, `ebx` and `eax`  will be "random". Also are you sure the stack is kept aligned with a `subq $8, %rsp`?

Comment: @knm241 The stack is aligned with the `subq` because the stack was aligned when `print` was called, and the OS uses 8 bytes to push the instruction pointer, meaning I need to use another 8 bytes to align the stack.I tried commenting out the `print` call before the `idiv` instruction, and it worked perfectly (thanks!), but I still want to know why print was breaking the `idiv`. I tried to push `%rax` and `%rbx` (16 byte total), then pop them to restore the registers to their original values, but it still failed.

Comment: @knm241 Found why it was breaking. `_printf` also changed `%rdx`, so after pushing and popping (to restore) that register in `print` as well, it all works. Thanks for your help! Make your comment an answer and I will check and up vote.